# Loading and running Javascript modules depending on current page

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, vue.js

I've a multi-page website built using Laravel and I'm now looking into how to structure the Javascript front-end. The Javascript will be for small things such as showing/hiding components on button click, Ajax calls when submitting a form, appending components to the DOM, resizing/positioning components created in Laravel/Blade.

### Pure JS example:

```
//navbar.js

export function exec() {
    var hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger");
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu");

    hamburger.onclick = function() {
        menu.classList.toggle("expanded");
    };
};

// app.js

var navbar = require('./navbar');
/* more imports */

navbar.exec();
/* more executions of modules*/
```

I've split up the code into [(ES2015) modules](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#modules) which are then concatenated using [browserify](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir#browserify). That means that everything tries to execute on every page. How should I structure the loading of the modules in the main file so that it only loads the necessary modules based on the current page?

I've looked into [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) and [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) for using routes with components and better structuring of components and rendering which seems to do kind of that but they seem to only be for single-page web apps.

### React example

```
//progressbar.js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var ProgressBar = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="ProgressBar">
                This is a progress bar.
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = ProgressBar;

//app.js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

var ProgressBar = require('./progressbar');

function renderToElements(toRender, elements) {
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    render(toRender, elements[i]);
  }
}

renderToElements(
    <ProgressBar />,
    document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar')
);
```

A problem with React (and I think Vue too) is that it seems that if I've created a component using Blade with variables created in PHP and I want to use this as a React component, I have to rerender the component in React. How do I then keep these variables? Do I have to make a Ajax call to the server and get that value again?

### Laravel + React example

```
//somepage.blade.php
/* other code */
<div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="bar" style="width: {{$product->progress}}%">
        <span>
            <span class="sum">{{$product->progress}}</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
/* other code */

//progressbar.js
var ProgressBar = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="ProgressBar">
                This is a progress bar.
            </div>
        );
    },
    handleResize: function(e) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hey, i`m currently in the same dilemma. Vue is awesome for SPA-s but for a normal website you cant manage modules with it. Would love to hear how you managed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use React router and define the routes as:

```
<Router>
  <Route name="welcome" />
  <Route name="about" />
  ...
</Router>
```

You will see it's really easy and straight forward to use, and of course it will simplify your app a lot.

Comment: How would I actually use this? Like I said, among other things I want to resize and position elements created on the server using Laravel/Blade. How would I use react router for this?